# .Net Core : i want to create table at the same page where values are

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create table under inputs when i click button. If i click more then one to button i want to add new values to table also. I don't want to go new view so table should be in same view where inputs are.

this is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index()
{

     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(Bilgi bilgi)
{
     return View();
}
```

this is my model:

```
public class Bilgi
{     

     public string insankaynagi { get; set; }
     public string birim { get; set; }
     public string miktar { get; set; }      

}
```

and this is my view

```
@model Bilgi    
@{
    Layout = null;
}    
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" asp-action="Index">
 <p>
            <label asp-for="insankaynagi"> Proje Özeti  </label>
            <input asp-for="insankaynagi" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label asp-for="birim"> Birim  </label>
            <input asp-for="birim" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label asp-for="miktar"> Miktar  </label>
            <input asp-for="miktar" />
        </p>
 <p>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </p>

 </form>
```

Comment: am I correct that you want to show the table under the form?if yes you should send ajax request to your backend and build a table using javascript.

Comment: Not exactly under the form. I will add more inputs and more tables so tables should be in form.

Comment: Basically any dynamic things achieved with JavaScript

Comment: If you simply want to display results in the same page, you can add the results as an array property in the model and display them in the view. You'd need JavaScript only if you wanted to avoid the postback

Comment: So do you want to combine the Create View and Index View of  `Bilgi` in the same view?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have provide you answer after puting some logic for data extraction you can show data on the same form.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index()
{

     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(Bilgi bilgi)
{
     // Write Code for Submit
     bilgi=LoadBilgi();
     return View(bilgi);
}

[NoAction]
public Bilgi LoadBilgi()
{
     Bilgi newBilgi= new Bilgi ();
     // Load data and assign to newBilgi
     return newBilgi;
}
```

**View**

```
@model Bilgi    
@{
    Layout = null;
}    
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" asp-action="Index">
 <p>
            <label asp-for="insankaynagi"> Proje Özeti  </label>
            <input asp-for="insankaynagi" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label asp-for="birim"> Birim  </label>
            <input asp-for="birim" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label asp-for="miktar"> Miktar  </label>
            <input asp-for="miktar" />
        </p>
 <p>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </p>

@if(Model != null)
{
 <table>
 <thead>
  <tr><th>insankaynagi</th></tr>
  <tr><th>birim</th></tr>
  <tr><th>miktar</th></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>@Model.insankaynagi</td>
      <td>@Model.birim</td>
      <td>@Model.miktar</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
}

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to combine a create view and Index view. I recommend that you could use [`ViewComponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to achieve it.

You could set the table which displays all data in a view component and append it to the create form.

Below is a simple demo:

1.Take Bilgi.cs as example:

```
public class Bilgi
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string insankaynagi { get; set; }
    public string birim { get; set; }
    public string miktar { get; set; } 

}

public DbSet<Bilgi> Bilgis{ get; set; }
```

2.Create a ViewComponent in `MyApp/ViewComponents` folder(create the folder `ViewComponents` if it does not exist)

```
public class BilgisTableViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;
    public BilgisTableViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View(await db.Bilgis.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

3.Create the `Views/Shared/Components folder`. This folder must be named `Components`.

4.Create a `Views/Shared/Components/BilgisTable/Default.cshtml` Razor view to show the table, the folder name `BilgisTable` corresponds to `BilgisTableViewComponent`

```
@model IEnumerable<Bilgi>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.insankaynagi)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.birim )
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.miktar)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.insankaynagi)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.birim)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.miktar)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

5.In Index View, invoke the ViewComponent

```
@model Bilgi

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="insankaynagi" class="control-label">Proje Özeti </label>
                <input asp-for="insankaynagi" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="birim" class="control-label">Birim </label>
                <input asp-for="birim" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="miktar" class="control-label">Miktar  </label>
                <input asp-for="miktar" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@await Component.InvokeAsync("BilgisTable")
```

6.Action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{       
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Bilgi bilgi)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(bilgi);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View();

}
```